# An assumption in pcf theory

Tags: set-theory

Often in theorems of pcf theory one has the assumption that the length of sequences of functions has to respect some bound so things can be well-defined. For instance, let $a=[\aleph_2,...,\aleph_n,...:n<\omega]$ be a set of regular cardinals, say you have a sequence $f_\beta$  in $\prod a$ of length at most $|a|^+$. Then $sup_\beta f_\beta \in \prod a$ since $|a|^+ < min(a)$. But why is this true? If you have for example an $\omega_2$ sequence of functions $f:\kappa \rightarrow \kappa$ such that $f(\kappa)\in \kappa$, $\kappa$ some $\aleph_n$, $n$ not 0 and not 1,then why is $f_\beta$ for $\beta=\omega_2$ outside of the product, as far as we know, we don't know if $2^{\aleph_0}= \aleph_2 $ since $a$ is a countable set of regular cardinals (say the set of $\aleph_n$'s)? Thanks

Comment: There are several typos in your question, could you please read it over and edit appropriately.

Comment: I hope it is fixed now.

Comment: Not quite: You seem to be asking why $f_\beta \in \prod a$ when $f_\beta \in \prod a$. Also $|a|^+ < \min(a)$ is false when `$a = \{\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\dots\}$`.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, got confused, since $|a|^+$ is in this case is $\aleph_1$. Let me start $a$ at $\aleph_2$, and let me consider an $\aleph_2$ sequence of functions. I am editing this.

Comment: The question is still unclear. Could you state the so-called 'assumption' more precisely?

Comment: the assumption is "$|a|<min(a)$" or "$|a|^+<min(a)$" , it depends on what theorems we want to prove. Either one of these two basic pcf assumptions are used. Now I don't see why they influence the length of sequences of functions in the product $\prod a$  

Comment: Maybe you mean that $\sup_\beta f_\beta \in \prod a$?

Comment: Well maybe, but I don't know the cofinality of $\prod a$ for $a$ a set of regular cardinals like in my post. Not only all of them are in the product up to $|a|^+$ but any function indexed by an ordinal after $|a|^+$ is no longer in the product. I know this to be true (I take it on faith since it is used in all the main theorems of pcf theory) but don't see why it is true.

Comment: Francois's guess that you meant `$\sup_\beta f_\beta\in\prod a$` was also my first guess, but your reply to him makes me look for a new guess.  Your question doesn't assume any connection between the functions `$f_\alpha$` for different $\alpha$, so I see no reason why the index that has been arbitrarily assigned to a function should affect its membership in the product.  And, despite Francois's earlier comment, your question still infers `$f_\beta\in\prod a$` from the assumption `$f_\beta\in\prod a$` --- presumably not what you meant.

Comment: On second thought, yes, I want $sup_\beta f_\beta \in \prod a$ or for instance $\bigcup_{\alpha<\beta} f_\alpha \in \prod a$  since $\beta<|a|^+<min(a)$. Yes my problem is that I don't see why membership in the product is conditioned by $\beta<|a|^+<min(a)$  knowing that $|a|^+ = \aleph_1$ . Since actually on our set $a$  of regular cardinals like above we can define continuum many functions, so why can't I get an increasing sequence of functions $f_\beta$  with say $\beta< 2^{aleph_0}$ and their sup in the product? Why should the maximum length of a sequence be bounded by $|a|^+<min(a)$?

Comment: François and Andreas: I corrected the part "$sup_\beta f_\beta \in \prod a$ in my post. Sorry for this confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ be a set of regular cardinals. An element of $\prod a$ is a function $f:a \to \sup a$ such that $f(\kappa) < \kappa$ for every $\kappa \in a$. Suppose we are given a family $f_i$, $i \in I$, of elements of $\prod a$. In order to ensure that $\sup_{i \in I} f_i \in \prod a$ we need to make sure that $\sup_{i \in I} f_i(\kappa) < \kappa$ for every $\kappa \in a$. A sufficient condition for this is that $|I| < \min a$. Indeed, since $|I| < \mathrm{cf}(\kappa) = \kappa$, we then have $\sup_{i \in I} f_i(\kappa) < \kappa$ for every $\kappa \in a$. Thus the assumption $|a| < \min a$ ensures that the supremum of any sequence of elements of $\prod a$ with length less than $|a|^+$ has a supremum in $\prod a$.

Comment: Thank you François, but I am really disappointed as I should have figured this by myself. Somehow I had dropped the requirement that $f(\kappa)<\kappa$ and was being silly. I am kind of mad right now. It just hold by regularity of all the cardinals in $a$...